# Jenkins - trigger a project only if it's not already running

Tags: build, jenkins

Here's the situation I have:

1. Mini-test suite that runs on a build in ~1 hour
2. Full-test suite that runs on a build in ~12 hours

I want to trigger (1) continuously, and if (1) PASSES, then I want to trigger (2).

however, I don't want to queue up a ton of jobs of (2) when the build is stable and (1) is passing frequently. How can I set this up in Jenkins? Two possible solutions I can think of would be to

- somehow never allow Jenkins to keep a queue of jobs on (2), or
- only trigger (2) if it's not already running

but I don't know how to do either, any ideas?

Comment: Will the "Advance Project Options -> Quiet period" feature do what you want?

Comment: Try [BuildResultTrigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin) - although I am not 100% sure if it's gonna work the way you would like it to...

Comment: [Build Blocker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin) could be handy to achieve this, it also allows to configure blocking behaviour quite fine grained.

Answer (score 0):

```
A possible solution for : only trigger (2) if it's not already running

All jenkins jobs have their data exposed in XML and json format via this URL:
*http://jenkins_hostname/job/job_name/build_number/api/xml*

This XML has a section of <building> in which you will know if the job is building or not:
<building> false </building>


If you can somehow read this from scripts?/code? then you will always know if job is running.

Otherwise, there is a boolean groovy API which reads this data and returns true or false (can be used easily in pipelines):

*def JobName = 'JOB_NAME'
def nextJob = Hudson.instance.getItem(JobName)
def running = nextJob.lastBuild.building
if (running) {
   println "${nextJobName} is already running. Not launching"
} else {
   println "${nextJobName} is not running. Launching..."
}*
```